# How to do a curl call from 2 specific locations in the world in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, curl

I'm doing this in Ruby:

```
response = `curl -w \"%{response_code}\:%{time_total}\" https://google.com -o /dev/null -s`
response_code, time_total = response.split(':')
```

It's kind of a ping. This works perfectly and gives me an HTTP response code and total response time.

Now, I would like to do this call from 2 specific locations in the world (let's say from the US and from Germany).

How can I do that? Should I buy a static IP and then instruct curl to do the call from that IP somehow?

Any idea?

Comment: You have to run your code in both regions: the US and Germany. Maybe via AWS or Heroku.

Comment: Note that there are services for pinging URLs from different locations. Unless you are trying to build your own, using an existing one might be easier.

Comment: @Stefan we are on Heroku, the only thing I found is Quotaguard, but I'm not sure this would allow me to do a curl command from 2 different locations. We are building a tool internally and we cannot use existing tools.

Comment: Have a look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/regions – it seems like you can specify the region for an app quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

A machine is physically located somewhere. If you want to do a ping from another location, you would probably need to buy a VPS server in this another location and run the same code from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a proxy for this.  There are a lot of options out there.  I like [webshare](https://www.webshare.io/) and they have a free tier.  However, you may have to pay if you want a specific location.

Then you would need to configure curl to use the proxy.

There should be examples in the docs for your proxy provider, but here's a snippet from the curl help page:

```
 -x, --proxy [protocol://]host[:port] Use this proxy
```

Comment: Measuring ping time with a proxy involved could be tricky.